# Nuxt add global plugins memory leakage issue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-mixin

I'm on Nuxt 2.13 universal mode, and I have serious memory usage and leakage!!

so as I was looking for related issues, I found this in Nuxt Docs [Plugins - NuxtJS](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins/#inject-in-root--context) :

> Don't use Vue.use(), Vue.component(), and globally, don't plug anything in Vue inside this function, dedicated to Nuxt injection. It will cause a memory leak on the server-side.

can anyone tell me what that means??

I'm currently using many external plugins and some globally added mixins by `vue.component()` and `vue.use()` . may them be the problem?? (i also have an utils.js mixin file that includes many methods and computed data that is added globally to `nuxt.config`)

some of my plugins and mixins that added globally to `nuxt.config.js` file :

```js
// Vuetify 2
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader version "^2.1.1"
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'
import colors from "vuetify/es5/util/colors";
import '~/assets/vuetify.scss'
// let siteDirection = process.env.SITE_DIRECTION

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default ctx => {
  const vuetify = new Vuetify({
    rtl: process.env.SITE_DIRECTION === 'rtl' ,
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss','~/assets/colors.scss'],
    icons: {
      iconfont: 'mdi', // default - only for display purposes
    },
    theme: {
      dark: false, // From 2.0 You have to select the theme dark or light here
      themes: {
        dark: {
          primary: colors.deepPurple.lighten3,
          accent: colors.deepPurple.accent3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent4
        }
      }
    }
  })

  ctx.app.vuetify = vuetify
  ctx.$vuetify = vuetify.framework
}
```

```js
// Vue-Glide Package
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Glide, GlideSlide } from 'vue-glide-js'

Vue.component("vue-glide", Glide)
Vue.component("vue-glide-slide", GlideSlide)
```

```js
// Noty package
import Vue from "vue";
import Noty from "noty";

Vue.prototype.$noty = (type, text) => new Noty({
    layout:process.env.SITE_DIRECTION === 'rtl' ? 'bottomLeft' : 'bottomRight',
    type,
    text,
    timeout: 5000
});
```

```js
// vue-product-zoomer package
import Vue from 'vue'
import ProductZoomer from 'vue-product-zoomer'
Vue.use(ProductZoomer)
```

my Mixins are also added the default way:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

const FormattedPrice = {
    install(Vue){
      Vue.mixin({
        methods:{
          formattedPrice(price,options){
            if(price !== null && price !== undefined){
              if(typeof price === 'object'){
                let min = price.min ? Number(price.min).toLocaleString() : 0
                let max = price.min ? Number(price.max).toLocaleString() : 0
                return min + ' - ' + max + (options && options.noSign ? '' : this.currencySign)
              }else{
                // try {
                //   return price.toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + this.currencySign
                //   // return price.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + this.currencySign
                // } catch (error) {
                //   return Number(price).toLocaleString() + this.currencySign
                // }
                return Number(price).toLocaleString() + (options && options.noSign ? '' : this.currencySign)
              }
            }
            return '...' + (options && options.noSign ? '' : this.currencySign)
          }
        },
        computed:{
          currencySign(){
            return ' ' + this.shopInfo.currency.sign
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }
  
  Vue.use(FormattedPrice)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your question:

> Don't use Vue.use(), Vue.component(), and globally, don't plug anything in Vue inside this function, dedicated to Nuxt injection. It will cause a memory leak on the server-side.

See this [PR](https://github.com/nuxt/docs/pull/1973), which is the reason for that warning.

A more clear explanation would be that you should **not** call `Vue.use()` or  `Vue.component()` from **inside** an exported plugin function.  You should place the calls in the global scope, and simply apply them to the context.

Where I believe you're getting a memory leak is with calling `new Vuetify()` from inside the exported function.  It's entirely possible that they are calling `Vue.use()` or `Vue.component()` as a side effect to that call.

You should instead place that call in the global scope.  If this doesn't work, then you may want to consider creating a minimum reproducible example and opening an issue on the Nuxt GitHub repo.

```
// Vuetify 2
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader version "^2.1.1"
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'
import colors from "vuetify/es5/util/colors";
import '~/assets/vuetify.scss'
// let siteDirection = process.env.SITE_DIRECTION

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const vuetify = new Vuetify({
    rtl: process.env.SITE_DIRECTION === 'rtl' ,
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss','~/assets/colors.scss'],
    icons: {
      iconfont: 'mdi', // default - only for display purposes
    },
    theme: {
      dark: false, // From 2.0 You have to select the theme dark or light here
      themes: {
        dark: {
          primary: colors.deepPurple.lighten3,
          accent: colors.deepPurple.accent3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent4
        }
      }
    }
})

export default ctx => {
  

  ctx.app.vuetify = vuetify
  ctx.$vuetify = vuetify.framework
}
```

Comment: Hmmmm..... , tanx . So by what i got from your explaination, my other plugins and mixins are ok and there is no need to use `inject` . that warning in vue doc was about using `use()` and `component()` **inside** export function. btw , that vuetify plugin is from a year ago when nuxt was working with veutify v1 and i had to do it to use v2. gonna reinstall it according to vuetify docs

Comment: Yes, it looks like everything else is okay to me.  if you do update the Vuetify installation and this persists, I would try to create a minimum reproducible example, since it's not likely anything else that you've shown here

Comment: tanx, i would appreciate if you check this too (my whole leakage issue): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66841758/nuxt-huge-memory-usage-leakage-and-how-to-prevent